# Implementation of user.bot discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm doin a command that checks if a user is a bot or a normal user

```py
@client.command()
async def maybebot(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Cheks if a user is a bot", description="Let's find out!")
    if user.bot == True:
        embed.add_field(name="And..", value="It is!")
    if user.bot == False:
        embed.add_field(name="And...", value="It's not!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is not working, no traceback, no error. What i should do?

Comment: Is there any code to actually send the message with the embed?

Comment: yes, of course i didn't paste it for error, now i'm fixing

Comment: Do you have an external exception handler for this command? If so, please also show its code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def maybebot(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Checks if a user is a bot", description="Let's find out!")
    if user.bot:
        embed.add_field(name="And...", value="It is!")
    else:
        embed.add_field(name="And...", value="It's not!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```